# Create a filtered power set in reverse order

Tags: javascript, math, combinatorics

I'm not sure if what I need has a name, but it's pretty close to a power set. Here's the desire:

```
Input:[1,2,3,4]

Output:
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,4]
[1,3,4]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[1,4]
```

This differs from a power set in 3 ways:

1. All subsets include the first value (`1`)
2. The minimum size of any subset is 2
3. The order goes from longest to shortest

My current solution is to create a power set, filter out the values that don't start with the first value, and then reverse sort. This is too slow so I'm looking for a better solution.

From longest to shortest, I run a test on each subset until I find a set that returns true. That makes me wonder if I could use a generator so I don't have to create all values at once (nice to have, but not necessary since the max size is only ~25 members, or ~33MM sets).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried just making the power set of `input.slice(1)` (i.e., all elements of the array except the first) and then prepending the first element?

Comment: That solves #1, but the most expensive part is the reverse sort, which I'd still have to do, in addition to an unshift on each.

Answer (score 0):

Generating a power set is easily done using bit masks.

Consider the set `A = {1, 2, 3, 4}`. Define a 4 element boolean vector and denote it `I`. Now, define `B = { A[i] | I[i] = true }`. There are two things to notice:

1. `B` is obviously a subset of `A`.
2. By iterating over the possible values of `I` we can generate all subsets
3. A integer number's bits can be used as `I` by treating each of its bits as a single boolean value.

That being said, here's an algorithm that generates all subsets of an array:

```
"use strict";
var input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var isMemberInSet = function (indexingVector, _, index) {
    return indexingVector & (1 << index);
}

var subsetCount = Math.pow(2, input.length);
for (var indexingVector = 0; indexingVector < subsetCount; indexingVector++) {
    var subset = input.filter(isMemberInSet.bind(undefined, indexingVector));
    console.log(subset);
}
```

But we can do much better! In fact, a few simple modifications of the above algorithm can solve entirely your problem.

Firstly, as we need to always include the first value of your array, we need to mirror the indexing vector generation. In other words, redefine `B = { A[I.length - i - 1] | I[i] = true }`.

Secondly, we need to iterate the indexing vector in reverse order which means:

```
for (var i = subsetCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Thirdly, as we don't care for all subsets, but only for those of length > 2 we need not iterate all the way to 0, instead iterate only until `pow(2, input.length - 1)` as this is the indexing vector that contains only the first and second values and all the other values for indexing vector don't include the first value:

```
var subsetsContainingTheFirstValue = Math.pow(2, input.length - 1);
for (var i = subsetCount - 1; i > subsetsContainingTheFirstValue; i--)
```

Finally, we arrive at this code:

```
"use strict";   
var input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var integerSize = 32;

var isMemberInSet = function (indexingVector , _, index) {
    return indexingVector & (1 << (input.length - index - 1));
}

var subsetCount = Math.pow(2, input.length);
var subsetsContainingTheFirstValue = Math.pow(2, input.length - 1);
for (var indexingVector  = subsetCount - 1; indexingVector  > subsetsContainingTheFirstValue; indexingVector --) {
    var subset = input.filter(isMemberInSet.bind(undefined, indexingVector ));
    console.log(subset);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
```

**Note:** The code above works thanks to the fact that you mentioned that the maximum number of elements is 25. If that number was more than 32, we wouldn't have been able to use integers and would have instead needed boolean arrays.

Comment: This is great (and I'm gonna have to re-read a chapter on bitwise operators to understand it). The only problem is requirement #3 where `[1,2]` comes before `[1,3,4]`. Any thoughts on how to order by length without using a sort over the entire set?

Comment: Aah, crap, I've misread your required output. Sadly, the method will always output the sets in lexicographical order so you'd need to sort them by length manually. Make sure to use a stable sorting algorithm as otherwise you'll lose the lexicographical ordering.